# Usage of factory, service and providers

Tags: angularjs, factory

I am new to AngularJS. I have seen many snippets on factory, service and providers. But I don't understand the exact usage of them. Please let me know the appropriate use of them. In which case should I use factory and when not to use?

Comment: The main difference is a service is a constructor function, and a factory is just a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read in

> [AngularJS: Service vs provider vs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angularjs-service-vs-provider-vs-factory/15666049#15666049)
>   and
>
> https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#factories

Hope it help !